# Receive share file intents with Flutter with IOS

Tags: flutter

I'm using the following plugin

https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent

It is working with android.

But the instruction for IOS are unclear - I follow the IOS instruction and I'm able to share files with my app, when I do so, my app opens but the flutter code is not executed, the only thing I see in the log is:

`6.26.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023000] Deep Link Web URL query is empty`

Which doesn't mean any thing to me.

I tried to look for this error and couldn't find anything that is related to sharing intent.

Can someone clarify this?

Is there a tutorial on how to set sharing intent for IOS?

In the instruction it says:

```
ios/Runner/Runner.entitlements

....
    <!--TODO:  Add this tag, if you want support opening urls into your app-->
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:example.com</string>
    </array>
```

But I don't have such file in my directory structure, any idea how to set it correctly?
....

EDIT:

1. I created and added the file `ios/Runner/Runner.entitlements` manually
2. I noticed I missed the last step (after publishing the question), so I did it:

   3. Add Runner and Share Extension in the same group
      Go to the Capabilities tab and switch on the App Groups switch for both targets. Add a new group and name it group.YOUR_HOST_APP_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in my case group.com.kasem.sharing

This step is not very clear:

- the name of the tab is `Signing & Capabilities`
- in order to switch on the App Group you should click on `+ Capability' in the top left of the tab
- I checked the checkbox next to `App Group`
- Add a new group and name it group.YOUR_HOST_APP_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in my case group.com.kasem.sharing

[image]

After this I was able to receive the file intent in the App but couldn't open the file:

print("$path, exist ${await io.File(path).exists()}");

I was able to print the path but the `exists` method return false

NOTE:

1. works with no issues in android
2. works with no issues in IOS when sharing an image
3. only fails with files (PDF)

Comment: I'm running into this as well now. I have modified the SharedMediaFile path entry to remove the leading "file://", but it still can't open the file. Did you solve it in the end?